# Does it matter if you divide loops into smaller loops?

Tags: java, loops, control-flow

If you have a for loop that has 2 main parts in it like this:

```
for (object o : objects){
doSomething(o);
doSomething2(o);
}
```

Does it hurt the performance when you split that loop into 2 smaller loops like this?

```
for (object o : objects){
doSomething(o);
}

for (object o : objects){
doSomething2(o);
}
```

Comment: Technically slightly worse, but it's O(n) either way. Don't worry about it until you actually have a problem. Use whichever makes your code easier to manage.

Comment: It hurts both performance and correctness if these two operations have to be done together.  Nano-optimizations like this are never a good idea unless you have data to support taking such a step.

Comment: @duffymo: LOL, we've moved past micro-optimization to nano-optimization, eh? Next up: pico!

Comment: It may be worse or better depending on the circumstances. Either measure it for the platform you are targeting or stop thinking about details like this.

Comment: In my comiler-design class, I studied about [Optimization via a sequence of loop transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization#Optimization_via_a_sequence_of_loop_transformations), especially [Loop fission/distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fission). It sometimes helps in locality of reference, only in certain context. If you'd suggest, I'll write an answer for the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Technically,* yes, you end up having to iterate twice. By definition except in a narrow band of possible operations, this is going to be slower than iterating once. You also have to allocate the iterator objects twice instead of once, etc., etc. If you're dealing with a massive list, I suppose two loops could cause more memory paging as well.

In the real world? You'd have to have a **very** big list, or a **really** slow iterator, for it to matter.

---

Subjectively: If you *can* do it either way (e.g., the order of the operations doesn't matter), I would do whichever makes the most sense in terms of writing and reading the code. For me, normally that would be one loop because then I see what's happening to each object quite clearly, but presumably you have a reason for asking. I wouldn't worry about the performance unless I knew I was going to be dealing with something truly massive (hundreds of thousands or even millions of entries), or I saw a *real world problem* with the code that I was addressing.

Comment: Ah, so the only significant difference in making the performance worse is the size of the object array?

Comment: Right (unless, as duffymo points out, it matters that the operations be done in the original order, in which case you have a bigger problem). But if you're talking about an array, youd' have to have a **really** big array for it to matter, I'd think.